# Syntax error on bash shell trying to perform a simple calculation

Tags: bash, bc

I'm having a syntax error ((standard_in): syntax error)on 3rd and 5th line.

```
#!/bin/bash
i=`echo "8.8007751822"|bc`
rws = `echo "0.49237251092*$i" |bc`
rmt = `echo "0.85 * $rws"| bc`
dx  = `echo "log ($rws / 0.000001) / 720.0" | bc`;
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) helpfully points out mistakes like this.

Comment: The error you describe comes from `bc`, though; if the code you're running is really what you're showing, the error would be `-bash: rws: command not found`.

Comment: @BenjaminW. I removed the spaces as mentioned on another answer you cited and I have no longer a syntax error but the error command not found.

Comment: "You command not found"?

Comment: I already used ShellCheck but some suggestions it makes does not work for me for example replacing i=`echo "8.8007751822"` for i=$("8.8007751822")

Comment: That be just `i=8.8007751822`.

Comment: I have reopened the question as it's a mix of things going wrong here; I'll add a community wiki answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

- Assignments must not have blanks around the `=`
- `` i=`echo "8.8007751822"|bc` `` is a really complicated way to write `i=8.8007751822`
- `bc` has no function `log`, there's only `l` for the natural logarithm (and `l` requires the `-l` option to be enabled)

I would move everything into `bc` instead of calling it multiple times:

```sh
bc -l <<'EOF'
i = 8.8007751822
rws = i * 0.49237251092
rmt = 0.85 * rws
dx = (l(rws / 0.000001) / l(10)) / 720
dx
EOF
```

This prints the value of `dx`.